# Moving socket.io into controller

Tags: node.js, sockets, express

This is my app structure

```
controller
   routes.js
public
   jquery.js
socket.io.js
   app.js
index.html
```

The app.js file contains the socket program which emits the some message when user connects. Now the problem was how I emit the message from routes.

My nodejs code was below:

This is my app.js file code:

```
var express=require('express');
var app=express();
var server=require('http').createServer(app);
var io=require('socket.io').listen(server);
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/'));


io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
socket.emit('message',{msg:'hai'});
});

app.use('/cal',require('./controllers/route'));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

server.listen(3000);
```

This is my route.js code:

```
var express=require('express');
var route=express.Router();

route.get('/',function(req,res){

    //socket.emit('message',{msg:'hai'});
});

module.exports=route;
```

This is my index.html file code:

```
<htmL>
<head>
<title>Chat with socket.io and node.js</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="./public/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./public/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>

jQuery(function($){
var socket = io.connect();

socket.on('message',function(data){
alert(data.msg);
});

});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Routes has nothing to do with sockets. You have to listen on sockets, not on routes. Here's par of the docs (http://socket.io/docs/) for using Socket.IO with Express:

```
// server - app.js
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

server.listen(80);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
    socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    });
});


// client - index.js
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
    socket.on('news', function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
    });
</script>
```